# Open a new file in Java with desired Unix permissions?

Tags: java

Basically, I'm wondering if there is a secure equivalent to opening a file and then using Files.setPosixFilesPermissions to "r--------"? Doing it in step creates a window in which the permissions are incorrect, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=334

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you should create an appropriate `FileAttribute` and then use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29 method